# Unable to auto-refresh page element using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am playing around trying to make a chatbox, but I find myself unable to make it auto-reload the messages. 
I am using a database for the messages as there is insufficient permission for php to write files on my server.
Here is the code for the chatbox:

```
<input name="usermsg" id="usermsg" type="text"/>
    <button id="submitmsg" type="button" onclick="onSubmit()">Send</button>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="src/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
    function onSubmit(){
        //console.log('ghffgj');
        if($("#usermsg").val()) {
            //alert($("#usermsg").val());
            var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "src/add_reply.php", 
                data: {text: clientmsg},
            });

            $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
            return false;
        }
    }

    setInterval (loadLog, 3000);

    function loadLog(){   


        $.ajax({
            url: "src/chatlog.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){        
                $("#chatbox").html(data);      
            },
        });
    }
</script>
```

And the code for chatlog.php:

```
<?php
include('src/database_connect.php');

 $select_query = "SELECT author, send_date, message FROM chatbox";

 $chat_obj = $conn->query($select_query);

 while($row = $chat_obj->fetch_assoc()){
     echo "<div><span style='font-size: 10px'>(".$row['send_date'].")</span><b>".$row['author']."</b>: ".$row['message'];
 }

 $conn->close();

 ?>
```

Adding new messages in the database works, but I can't seem to be able to return the text I display on chatlog.php back to the chatbox page

Edit: I forgot to mention, the browser console displays this:
GET http://*domain*/chatbox/src/chatlog.php?_=1467644248226
500 Internal Server Error
29ms

---

I found a solution, as displayed below:
index.php (only the chatbox code):

```
        <input name="usermsg" id="usermsg" type="text"/>
    <button id="submitmsg" type="button" onclick="onSubmit()">Send</button>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="src/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>

<script>

    function onSubmit(){
        console.log($("#usermsg").val());
        if($("#usermsg").val()) {
            //alert($("#usermsg").val());
            var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "src/add_reply.php", 
                data: {text: clientmsg},
            });

            $("#usermsg").val("");
            return false;
        }
    }



    function loadLog(){   


        $.ajax({
            url: "src/chatlog.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){        
                $("#chatbox").html(data); 
            },
        })/*.done(function(msg) {
          alert(msg);
        })*/;
    }

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        loadLog();
        setInterval (loadLog, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

chatbox.php :

```
<?php

 include('database_connect.php');

 $select_query = "SELECT author, send_date, message FROM chatbox";

 $chat_obj = $conn->query($select_query);

 //$chat_list = array();
 $content = "";
 while($row = $chat_obj->fetch_assoc()){
     //$chat_list[] = $row;
      $content .= "<div><span style='font-size: 10px'>(" . 
         $row['send_date'].")</span><b>".
         $row['author']."</b>: ".$row['message']."</div>";
 }

 $conn->close();
 die($content);
 ?>
```

Comment: So `chatlog.php` returns nothing?

Comment: It gets me something like 
GET http://domain/chatbox/src/chatlog.php?_=1467644248226 500 Internal Server Error 29ms
in the browser console

Comment: If it's a 500 Internal Server Error, then there's a more serious issue and you should check your PHP logs for what the exact error is.